# Unable to navigate through the up and down arrow through keyboard in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a search box. when I am searching for something I am getting the list of names. and when we click on the name I am doing something on top of this. But I want to navigate from one name to other names through the up and down arrow through the keyboard. I am using react js.
Here is the sample code I have written.

```
function App() {
  const [names, setnames] = useState([{
  "name": "Barbara-anne"
}, {
  "name": "Debi prasad Debi"
}, {
  "name": "Cara new Cara"
}, {
  "name": "access"
}, {
  "name": "access aaa"
}, {
  "name": "Joellyn"
}, {
  "name": "Elmo"
}, {
  "name": "Ivette"
}, {
  "name": "Lea"
}, {
  "name": "Michel"
}, {
  "name": "Leigha"
}, {
  "name": "Titus"
}, {
  "name": "Nollie"
}, {
  "name": "Celle"
}, {
  "name": "Thea"
}, {
  "name": "Brynn"
}, {
  "name": "Sloane"
}, {
  "name": "Margalo"
}, {
  "name": "Genevieve"
}, {
  "name": "Niel"
}, {
  "name": "Heddi"
}, {
  "name": "Gregg"
}, {
  "name": "Eduard"
}, {
  "name": "Kizzee"
}, {
  "name": "Truman"
}, {
  "name": "Merill"
}, {
  "name": "Lindie"
}, {
  "name": "Vasily"
}, {
  "name": "Averil"
}, {
  "name": "Golda"
}, {
  "name": "Zorine"
}, {
  "name": "Odele"
}, {
  "name": "Amalie"
}, {
  "name": "Ilsa"
}, {
  "name": "Pepillo"
}, {
  "name": "Hewe"
}, {
  "name": "Byrann"
}, {
  "name": "Alford"
}, {
  "name": "Lanny"
}, {
  "name": "Kristina"
}, {
  "name": "Mar"
}, {
  "name": "Vittoria"
}, {
  "name": "Winslow"
}, {
  "name": "Ashlan"
}, {
  "name": "Gayelord"
}])
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const filteredName=names.filter((val)=>{
            if(searchTerm ===""){
                return val;
            }else if(val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                return val;
            }
        });
  const renderStatementResult = searchTerm && searchTerm.length > 0;
  return (
    <>
          <div className="srchField">
            <label for="statement">Statement Name</label>
            <div className="valueField">
              <input type="text" name="fileName" id="statement" data-validate="true" placeholder="Type Name" onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}}/>
                {
                  renderStatementResult ? <ul className="lookup-results">
                  {filteredName.map((value)=>(<li key={value.name}>
                    {/* {
                      value.name.split('').map((char) =>{
                        if (searchTerm.toLowerCase().split('').includes(char.toLowerCase())) {
                          return <span className="hl">{char}</span>
                        }else{
                          return <span>{char}</span>
                        }
                      })
                    }                      */}
                    <Highlighter highlightClassName="hl" searchWords={[searchTerm]} autoEscape={true} textToHighlight={value.name}/>

                  </li>))}
                </ul> : null
                }
            </div>
          </div>
            
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`everything is working. I just want to navigate through the keyboard by pressing the up and down arrow.`

1. Can anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem.

   ```
    I am using react js.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use your keyboard is that you rendered out a simple list with items as a result of your search. Users cannot move through `<ul>` lists on any website with their arrow keys.

What you can do is either:

1. use an existing library like [React-Dropdown-Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-select) -> which will do all the heavy lifting for you. All you have to do is pass a list of your items and a callback function on click.
2. try and roll your own solution. Honestly you're halfway there with the search function you wrote. But you would need to re-write your JSX so it would use a `<select>` instead of `<ul>` and possibly some other changes.